# How come pending comments are appearing in admin?

Tags: comments

How come pending comments are appearing in our admin dashboard? We haven't enabled comments in any way and aren't really interested in that feature. How did someone manage to "add" a comment.

Some of them do appear to be genuine mentions of our blog post in Twitter, while others are rubbish.

What would happen if we approved them?

Comment: Are they comments or are they pingbacks? If they are pingbacks - links to and mentions of your site from other blogs (not a comment posted on your own blog) make sure this is unchecked in Settings -> Administration `Allow link notifications from other blogs (pingbacks and trackbacks.) `

Comment: yes, that option is ticked. Interesting ... how did my dashboard get alerted to the mentions? Surely my site isn't spidering the web looking for mentions?

Comment: @eileen - also what would happen if i approved one?

Comment: pingbacking is default in wordpress. If you don't want to know that you're being pinged, just unclick that setting. Like @Fernando said, you can publish them if you want, but if your theme doesn't have the comment template they won't show up on your post anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your dashboard got alerted by [trackbacks](http://codex.wordpress.org/Introduction_to_Blogging#Trackbacks) and [pingbacks](http://codex.wordpress.org/Introduction_to_Blogging#Pingbacks). Check the links for more info. As @eileen.carpenter mentioned on the comments, you should uncheck `Allow link notifications from other blogs (pingbacks and trackbacks.)` in your dashboard for them to be disabled.

If you approve them, they'll appear as comments in your posts/pages. Depending on the theme, they may actually appear as comments or trackbacks/pingbacks. Most modern themes display them differently. On code level, they're just comments with a different [comment_type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comment_type). So theme developers use this to display comments and trackbacks/pingback as different things.